# Makefile claiming a file is created when it isn't

Tags: windows, makefile, mingw

I've tried searching for someone with a similar issue for the past half hour but, I can't find anything for why this is showing that the file is up to date when it doesn't exist at all.

Here's the makefile as it is now:

```
SOURCES = \
Core\SnowApp.cpp \
Core\SnowApp_Render.cpp \
Core\SnowApp_Tick.cpp \
Core\InputState.cpp \
Graphics\RenderingScreen.cpp \
Graphics\SpriteSheet.cpp \
Maps\Map.cpp \
Entities\Entity.cpp \
Entities\MovingEntity.cpp \
Entities\Player.cpp \

_SOURCES = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
OBJECTS = $(subst \,_,$(_SOURCES))
SRCDIR=src
OBJDIR=obj
BINDIR=bin
EXECUTABLE=snow.exe

CFLAGS= -c -Wall
LFLAGS= -o
LLIBS= -lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL
CC=g++

COMPILE=$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) $@ $<
LINK=$(CC) $(LFLAGS) $@ $^ $(LLIBS)

$(BINDIR)\$(EXECUTABLE): $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)\,$(OBJECTS))
    $(LINK)

$(OBJDIR)\Core_SnowApp.o: \
$(SRCDIR)\Core\SnowApp.cpp $(SRCDIR)\Core\SnowApp.h \
$(SRCDIR)\Graphics\RenderingScreen.h $(SRCDIR)\Maps\Map.h \
$(SRCDIR)\Core\InputState.h
    $(COMPILE)

$(OBJDIR)\Core_SnowApp_Render.o: \
$(SRCDIR)\Core\SnowApp_Render.cpp $(SRCDIR)\Core\SnowApp.h \
$(SRCDIR)\Graphics\RenderingScreen.h
    $(COMPILE)

$(OBJDIR)\Core_SnowApp_Tick.o: \
$(SRCDIR)\Core\SnowApp_Tick.cpp $(SRCDIR)\Core\SnowApp.h
    $(COMPILE)

$(OBJDIR)\Core_InputState.o: \
$(SRCDIR)\Core\InputState.cpp $(SRCDIR)\Core\InputState.h
    $(COMPILE)

$(OBJDIR)\Graphics_SpriteSheet.o: \
$(SRCDIR)\Graphics\SpriteSheet.cpp $(SRCDIR)\Graphics\SpriteSheet.h
    $(COMPILE)

$(OBJDIR)\Graphics_RenderingScreen.o: \
$(SRCDIR)\Graphics\RenderingScreen.cpp $(SRCDIR)\Graphics\RenderingScreen.h \
$(SRCDIR)\Graphics\SpriteSheet.h
    $(COMPILE)

$(OBJDIR)\Maps_Map.o: \
$(SRCDIR)\Maps\Map.cpp $(SRCDIR)\Maps\Map.h \
$(SRCDIR)\Graphics\RenderingScreen.h $(SRCDIR)\Core\InputState.h
    $(COMPILE)

$(OBJDIR)\Entities_Entity.o: \
$(SRCDIR)\Entities\Entity.cpp $(SRCDIR)\Entities\Entity.h \
$(SRCDIR)\Graphics\RenderingScreen.h $(SRCDIR)\Core\InputState.h \
$(SRCDIR)\Maps\Map.h
    $(COMPILE)

$(OBJDIR)\Entities_Player.o: \
$(SRCDIR)\Entities\Player.cpp $(SRCDIR)\Entities\Player.h \
$(SRCDIR)\Maps\Map.h $(SRCDIR)\Graphics\RenderingScreen.h \
$(SRCDIR)\Core\InputState.h
    $(COMIPLE)

$(OBJDIR)\Entities_MovingEntity.o: \
$(SRCDIR)\Entities\MovingEntity.cpp $(SRCDIR)\Entities\MovingEntity.h \
$(SRCDIR)\Graphics\RenderingScreen.h $(SRCDIR)\Core\InputState.h \
$(SRCDIR)\Entities\Entity.h $(SRCDIR)\Maps\Map.h
    $(COMPILE)

clear:
    del /Q $(OBJDIR)\* $(BINDIR)\*

variables:
    echo $(SOURCES)
    echo $(OBJECTS)
    echo $(SRCDIR)
    echo $(OBJDIR)
    echo $(BINDIR)
    echo $(EXECUTABLE)
    echo $(COMPILE)
    echo $(LINK)

makefolders:
    if not exist $(SRCDIR) mkdir $(SRCDIR)
    if not exist $(OBJDIR) mkdir $(OBJDIR)
    if not exist $(BINDIR) mkdir $(BINDIR)
```

My issue is that when using mingw32-make, it will create all of the files except obj\Entities_Player.o, which it says is always up to date.  Here's some of the commandline output (I've renamed mingw32-make to make for ease of use):

```
C:\Users\Mike\Documents\CodeProjects\Snow\trunk>make clear
del /Q obj\* bin\*

C:\Users\Mike\Documents\CodeProjects\Snow\trunk>dir obj
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is D29B-6E0B

 Directory of C:\Users\Mike\Documents\CodeProjects\Snow\trunk\obj

03/13/2013  11:33 AM    <DIR>          .
03/13/2013  11:33 AM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  80,363,814,912 bytes free

C:\Users\Mike\Documents\CodeProjects\Snow\trunk>make
g++ -c -Wall -o obj\Core_SnowApp.o src\Core\SnowApp.cpp
g++ -c -Wall -o obj\Core_SnowApp_Render.o src\Core\SnowApp_Render.cpp
g++ -c -Wall -o obj\Core_SnowApp_Tick.o src\Core\SnowApp_Tick.cpp
g++ -c -Wall -o obj\Core_InputState.o src\Core\InputState.cpp
g++ -c -Wall -o obj\Graphics_RenderingScreen.o src\Graphics\RenderingScreen.cpp
g++ -c -Wall -o obj\Graphics_SpriteSheet.o src\Graphics\SpriteSheet.cpp
g++ -c -Wall -o obj\Maps_Map.o src\Maps\Map.cpp
g++ -c -Wall -o obj\Entities_Entity.o src\Entities\Entity.cpp
g++ -c -Wall -o obj\Entities_MovingEntity.o src\Entities\MovingEntity.cpp
g++ -o bin\snow.exe obj\Core_SnowApp.o obj\Core_SnowApp_Render.o obj\Core_SnowAp
p_Tick.o obj\Core_InputState.o obj\Graphics_RenderingScreen.o obj\Graphics_Sprit
eSheet.o obj\Maps_Map.o obj\Entities_Entity.o obj\Entities_MovingEntity.o obj\En
tities_Player.o -lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL
g++: error: obj\Entities_Player.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [bin\snow.exe] Error 1

C:\Users\Mike\Documents\CodeProjects\Snow\trunk>make obj\Entities_Player.o
make: `obj\Entities_Player.o' is up to date.

C:\Users\Mike\Documents\CodeProjects\Snow\trunk>dir obj\Entities_Player.o
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is D29B-6E0B

 Directory of C:\Users\Mike\Documents\CodeProjects\Snow\trunk\obj

File Not Found

C:\Users\Mike\Documents\CodeProjects\Snow\trunk>
```

First, I empty my obj directory and show that it's empty.  Then I call make which, for my past files in the SOURCES variable, builds all the .cpp files into .o files residing in obj.  This step skips obj\Entities_Player.o so, we check it by itself and see that it's up to date but, it wasn't found.  We check again to see if the .o file is in the directory, and it isn't.  For what it's worth, if I compile it manually using g++ and going through the $(COMPILE) line by hand, I end up being able to compile the file, then make the project:

```
C:\Users\Mike\Documents\CodeProjects\Snow\trunk>g++ -c -Wall -o obj\Entities_Pla
yer.o src\Entities\Player.cpp

C:\Users\Mike\Documents\CodeProjects\Snow\trunk>make
g++ -o bin\snow.exe obj\Core_SnowApp.o obj\Core_SnowApp_Render.o obj\Core_SnowAp
p_Tick.o obj\Core_InputState.o obj\Graphics_RenderingScreen.o obj\Graphics_Sprit
eSheet.o obj\Maps_Map.o obj\Entities_Entity.o obj\Entities_MovingEntity.o obj\En
tities_Player.o -lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL

C:\Users\Mike\Documents\CodeProjects\Snow\trunk>
```

Maybe I just need a fresh set of eyes on it, maybe there's something about make that I'm not aware of.  If you can think of anything at all, I'd really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in your make file. The build command for Player is :

```
 $(COMIPLE)
```

when it should be:

```
$(COMPILE)
```

`$(COMIPLE)` evaluates to nothing, so no action is performed.

Comment: And the fresh set of eyes is the winner!  Thank you!

Comment: Always run make with the `--warn-undefined-variables` parameter!